# Proof that the sum of two real measurable functions is measurable.

Tags: measure-theory, product-measure

Let $f, g : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be measurable functions. Show that: $(x, y) \rightarrow f(x) + g(y)$ is measurable in the sense of the product measure.

Ok, I figured out a way to do this by proving that $(x,y) \rightarrow (f(x), g(y))$ is measurable and then move on to prove that $(x,y) \rightarrow x+y$ is measurable and finally apply these results to the compound of the two. However I am unable to prove that $x+y$ is measurable. Would anyone care to give me a tip?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The map $(x,y) \mapsto x + y$ is measurable because it is continuous.  Do you understand why?

Comment: Not imediatelly, no. Would you enlighten me?

Comment: @RodrigoMeireles Do you know what the Borel $\sigma$-algebra is?  And what a Borel measurable function is?

Comment: Yes, I do. However the $\sigma$-algebra here is not specified, so I didn't think that borelians would help. But go on, please.

Comment: @RodrigoMeireles As I understand it, if the $\sigma$-algebra is not specified and we are over $\Bbb R$ or $\Bbb R^{n}$, then saying "measurable" means Lebesgue measurable.  Now, if $\mathcal{B}(\Bbb R^{2})$ is the Borel $\sigma$-algebra, and $\Sigma(m^{*})$ is the $\sigma$-algebra of Lebesgue measurable sets, then since $\mathcal{B}(\Bbb R^{2}) \subseteq \Sigma(m^{*})$, we have that Borel measurable functions are Lebesgue measurable.

Comment: @RodrigoMeireles So, since continuous functions are Borel measurable, they are Lebesgue measurable.  But you should of course prove that $(x,y) \mapsto x + y$ is continuous in the first place.

Comment: Thank you, I will make that assumption to solve the problem. Do you think this question can be answered to any $\sigma$-algebra?

Comment: @RodrigoMeireles Here is where we are at: $f, g: \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$.  The codomain is usually assumed to have the Borel $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{B}(\Bbb R)$ on it.  The domain can have any $\sigma$-algebra $\Sigma$ on it.  So $f, g: (\Bbb R, \Sigma) \to (\Bbb R, \mathcal{B}(\Bbb R))$ are measurable.  Now you want to prove $f(x) + g(y) : (\Bbb R \times \Bbb R, \Sigma \times \Sigma) \to (\Bbb R \times \Bbb R \to \mathcal{B}(\Bbb R \times \Bbb R))$ is measurable.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32285/discussion-between-rodrigo-meireles-and-user46944).

Answer (score 1):

A more complicated answer: Let f,g be measurable real functions.Let $a,b\in R$ with $a<b.$ Let $c=(b-a)/2.$ Let $h=f+g.$  Define $$S(a,b)=\cup_{q\in Q}[f^{-1}(a-q,a-q+c)]\cap  g^{-1}(q,q+c).$$ Then $S(a,b)=h^{-1}(a,b)$ because:

(1) If $h(x)\in (a,b),$ take  $q\in (f(x)-c,f(x))\cap Q,$ so $f(x)\in (a-q,a-q+c),$ and we must have also $g(x)\in (q,q+c)$ to satisfy $f(x)+g(x)\in (a,b)=(a,[a-q+c]+[q+c]).$ So $x\in S(a,b)$.... And

(2) If $x\in S(a,b)$ then for some $q\in Q$ we have $h(x)\in ([a-q]+q,[a-q+c]+[q+c])=(a,b).$

Every $S(a,b)$ is a measurable set by the def'n of $S(a,b).$ So $h^{-1}V$ is a measurable set whenever $V$ is a  bounded open interval. So $h^{-1}W$ is a measurable set whenever $W$ is open, because  $W=\cup H$ where $H$ is a  countable set of bounded open intervals, and $h^{-1}W=\cup_{U\in H}h^{-1}U.$